# expo v29 not loading assets in ios release build

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been using expo with ExpoKit since v23 and made some iOS releases with those versions, when upgraded to release 29, debug build was working fine as usual.

But when I created a release build, all images stopped showing.

In this gist I share my podfile, app.json and package.json: https://gist.github.com/jper92/f705c71c455c760bd6c10e9cbdeac16c

Also made sure to update the `EXShell.info` file with the correct versions, tried to add and remove the local bundling, caching them in the initial splash with `Asset.fromModule`, and carefully read all steps to upgrade to v29 and I'm still having the issue, any suggestion?

Comment: Are images just don't exist in the final bundle, or are images still trying to fetch from the CDN? If you are sure the images are trying to be loaded from bundle, I think you should create a clean project with all your components etc, and submit this to github as an issue. Expokit support for upgrades are not that great tbh.

Comment: They're being bundled, anyway, I already tried not to bundle them and fetch them at app's startup using the `Asset.fromModule().downloadAsync` but that didn't work either. They are uploaded correctly to the CDN because former versions fetch the images from there with no problems.

Comment: I think you should create a new project and eject it, copy your all related files, it would probably work. Expo's upgrade workflow for expokit is really complicated and not sure we can just point out what is wrong with your particular project. Worked for me when I had a similar same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try tomorrow, maybe that solves the issue. I was hoping I didn't have to eject it again though

Comment: I already undetached and detached again the project, and now sometimes the images load but most of the time they don't...